# Are headings allowed in a TH in a table?

Tags: html

Are headings allowed in a TH in a table? I have read that they aren't but my Lighthouse audit doesnt pick them them.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"><h2>The table header</h2></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>The table body</td>
            <td>with two columns</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="2">
        <caption>Yes heading tags are allowed</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><h1>Hello</h1></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Hi, How are you...</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use them (of course nobody will force you to anything), if you wan't to customize text inside use `style=" css here "` or a `class="yourclass"` and specify it in CSS with

```
.yourclass
{
   /* css here */
}
```